# CardView with spinner or Expandable ListView

Tags: android, user-interface

Hi guys I'm trying to implement a UI which I have attached below: 
[image: view]

please suggest me in which way should I achieve it.

1) Using Custom CardView.
  2) Using Custom Expandable list View.

[screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iV6E.png)

Answer (score 2):

If you have too much items in your list, you have to use custom expandable list view. Because, you have to implement view holder pattern for better performance. Otherwise, you can inflate Custom CardViews in a layout and change visibilities to sub items.